# PHP+FIREBIRD - Trazer resultado de relações das tabelas

Tags: php, sql, firebird

No IBExpert a query abaixo traz os dados que corretamente, porem quando utilizo a mesma query no PHP não funciona.

```
SELECT
                FUNCIONARIOS.nome,
                 CNPJ,
                 cod_funcionario,
                 LOGRADOURO,
                 CONTATO,
                 cidade,
                 estado,
                 CEP,
                 inativo

         FROM FUNCIONARIOS,IFUNCIONARIOS,ENDERECOS_CADASTRO,FILIAIS
         WHERE
            FUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO = IFUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO
            AND FILIAIS.FILIAL = FUNCIONARIOS.FILIAL
            AND  IFUNCIONARIOS.GERADOR = ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.GERADOR
            AND CARGO IN ('0','10032713')
```

Veja abaixo como estou aplicando a query dentro com PHP;

```
//Instruções SQL

$sql = " SELECT
        *
     FROM 
        FUNCIONARIOS,
        IFUNCIONARIOS,
        ENDERECOS_CADASTRO,
        FILIAIS
     WHERE
        FUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO = IFUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO
        AND FILIAIS.FILIAL = FUNCIONARIOS.FILIAL
        AND  IFUNCIONARIOS.GERADOR = ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.GERADOR
        AND FUNCIONARIOS.CARGO IN ('0','10032713')
       ";
//Executa a instrução SQL
$query= ibase_query ($dbh, $sql);

//gera um loop com as linhas encontradas

while ($row = ibase_fetch_object ($query)) {
    $name = $row->FUNCIONARIOS.nome;
    $store_id = $row->CNPJ;
    $original_id =$row->COD_FUNCIONARIO;
    $street =$row->LOGRADOURO;
    $complement =$row->CONTATO;
    $city =$row->CIDADE;
    $uf =$row->ESTADO;
    $zipcode =$row->CEP;
    $is_active =$row->INATIVO;


// RESULTADO DA CONSULTA
echo "
    $name-
    $store_id-
    $original_id
    $street-
    $complement-
    $city-
    $uf-
    $zipcode-
    $is_active

<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema acrescentando os campos da tabela que desejo trazer os resultados.

O código ficou assim;

```
   //Instruções SQL

$sql = " SELECT
            **FUNCIONARIOS.NOME,
             FILIAIS.CNPJ,
             FUNCIONARIOS.COD_FUNCIONARIO,
             ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.LOGRADOURO,
             ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.CONTATO,
             ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.CIDADE,
             ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.ESTADO,
             ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.CEP,
             FUNCIONARIOS.INATIVO**
     FROM 
        FUNCIONARIOS,
        IFUNCIONARIOS,
        ENDERECOS_CADASTRO,
        FILIAIS
     WHERE
        FUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO = IFUNCIONARIOS.FUNCIONARIO
        AND FILIAIS.FILIAL = FUNCIONARIOS.FILIAL
        AND  IFUNCIONARIOS.GERADOR = ENDERECOS_CADASTRO.GERADOR
        AND FUNCIONARIOS.CARGO IN ('0','10032713')
       ";
//Executa a instrução SQL
$query= ibase_query ($dbh, $sql);

//gera um loop com as linhas encontradas

while ($row = ibase_fetch_object ($query)) {
    $name = $row->NOME;
    $store_id = $row->CNPJ;
    $original_id =$row->COD_FUNCIONARIO;
    $street =$row->LOGRADOURO;
    $complement =$row->CONTATO;
    $city =$row->CIDADE;
    $uf =$row->ESTADO;
    $zipcode =$row->CEP;
    $is_active =$row->INATIVO;


// RESULTADO DA CONSULTA
echo "
    $name-
    $store_id-
    $original_id
    $street-
    $complement-
    $city-
    $uf-
    $zipcode-
    $is_active


<br>";
}
```